# Доступ к базе данных через командную строку Windows

Tags: windows, sql-server

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести содержимое таблицы базы данных через командную строку Windows одной командой. Нужно вывести, не используя sqlcmd.

Comment: тоесть, вы хотите в стандартный cmd запихнуть sql запрос?

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, если возможно так, да. Главная цель - вывести содержимое таблицы каким-нибудь способом, используя командную строку windows

Comment: без программирования? вам нужен готовый продукт?

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите работать с sql server из консоли, не используя при этом стандартный консольный клиент для sql server? Зачем?

Comment: @PashaPash, если вы о sql server management studio, то им я умею пользоваться. Я изучаю предмет "базы данных" в ВУЗе и мне дали такое задание.

Comment: @Uchenitsa стандартный консольный клиент - для работы с сервером через командную строку - это sqlcmd. Суть задания - именно обойтись без него?

Comment: @PashaPash, мне дали задание - вывести содержимое таблицы базы данных, используя командную строку винды. Я нашла решение с использованием sqlcmd. Оно пишется в несколько команд (подключение к серверу, затем сам запрос). Такое решение не подошло. Попросили вывести таблицу одной командой и запретили использовать sqlcmd

Comment: Вы по-видимому использовали sqlcmd в интерактивном режиме, но скрипты sqlcmd может выполнять и одной командой, если задать параметром имя файла скрипта, или непосредственно текст скрипта, напр. `sqlcmd -S hostName -d dbName -Q "select * from TableName"`. Однако вот это: "_запретили использовать sqlcmd_" - довольно странное требование. А как ещё? Можно наверное для powershell скрипт написать. Или powershell тоже запрещено использовать?

Comment: @i-one, а как будет выглядеть скрипт для powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одной командой с помощью *sqlcmd*:

```
sqlcmd -S hostName -d dbName -Q "select * from TableName"
```

Если *sqlcmd* нельзя использовать, то ещё один вариант - использование *powershell*. Для этого создаём текстовый файл с раширением `.ps1` примерно такого содержания:

```
$hostName = "hostName"
$dbName = "dbName"

$connectionString = "Server = $hostName; Database = $dbName; Integrated Security = True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TableName"
$cmd.Connection = $connection
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$adapter.SelectCommand = $cmd
$dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$adapter.Fill($dataTable) > $null
$connection.Close()

foreach ($row in $dataTable.Rows)
{
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $dataTable.Columns.Count; $i++)
    {
        $colName = $dataTable.Columns[$i];
        $val = $row.ItemArray[$i];

        if ([DBNull]::Value.Equals($val))
        {
            write-host $colName " = NULL"
        }
        else
        {
            write-host $colName " = " $val
        }
    }
    write-host
}
```

который потом запускается из консоли одной командой

```
powershell -File <ИмяФайлаСкрипта>.ps1
```

Comment: Для powershell есть еще Invoke-Sqlcmd, но требует установленного SQL Server.

Comment: @i-one, спасибо за ответ! Мне дали подсказку, что нужно, используя gscript или vscript написать небольшую программку, которая будет выводить содержимое таблицы

Answer (score 0):

[Программа bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms162802.aspx)

> Программа bcp используется для копирования данных между
>   SQL Server и файлом данных в пользовательском формате.
>   С помощью программы bcp можно выполнять ... экспорт данных из таблиц в файлы данных.